# C++ .NET (График функции)

Tags: c++, .net

Visual Studio 2012, С++ .NET Framework. В форме задаются два числа **a**, **b**. Надо, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку появился график кривой y=a*x^2+b.
Какой элемент лучше всего использовать для вывода графика на экран?
Подойдёт ли для этого обычный **PictureBox**, или есть что-то лучше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PictureBox вполне подойдет. Он как раз и предназначен для таких вещей. Если график нужно нарисовать 1 раз, то элемент управления не очень важен (можно рисовать прям на форме). Если же нужна быстрая перерисовка изображения, добавление новых деталей поверх старых (работа с Image и BackgroundImage), то тут конечно стоит использовать элемент с хорошей буферизацией, предназначенный для графики, коим и является PictureBox.

Comment: Может тогда сразу подскажите:
Есть форма с PictureBox1. и два массива значений, x[i], y[i], соответствующие координатам точек, которые будут образовывать график на PicuteBox. Для рисования графика я использую

graf1->FillEllipse(c, x[i], y[i] , 1, 1);//в цикле

Если я начинаю рисовать в конструкторе класса, соотвествующий форме с pictureBox1, то ничего не получается (pictureBox1 загружается позже походу, чем конструктор)Пробовал рисовать график используя и другие разные обработчики событий формы и pictureBox1.

Собственно как мне сделать так, чтобы график  отобразился сразу?

Comment: @usk-dima попробуйте событие Shown формы (происходит когда все уже загрузилось и форма стала себя рисовать, еще есть событие Paint - происходит кода форме надо перерисоваться) .

Comment: пробовал, не получилось.

что ещё меня удивило, что не сработало даже так:
graph^ g = gcnew graph(uc1, ic1, size);
    g->Show();
    g->printGraph();

это обработчик нажатия кнопки, когда запускается форма с графом. printGraph() -ф-я рисующая графф

Comment: @usk-dima А график вообще нарисовать  получается хоть как-то?

Comment: Да. НА форму с PictureBox1 (на котором должен быть график) добавил кнопку, при нажатии на которую срабатывает printGraph(): всё сработало

Comment: @usk-dima не знаю в чем дело. Оформите в вопрос, может кто-то опытнее вам поможет.